# Object is deallocated immediately if created in initializer, but not if created in method

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I have the following class:

```
@implementation MyUICollectionViewCell {
    CAShapeLayer *layr;
}


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.layer.mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        layr = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initMask {
    self.layer.mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
}

- (void)updateMask {   
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = (CAShapeLayer*) self.layer.mask;
    maskLayer.frame = ...;
    maskLayer.path = ...;
}

@end
```

If I assign `self.layer.mask` in constructor, it is `nil` in `updateMask` method. However, if assignment is done in `initMask` method (called from outside the class), everything works fine.

Can anybody explain what's going on here?

---

**EDIT:**
Tried storing the object in ivar (namely `layr`), but to no avail - it is still `nil` in `updateMask`.

Comment: Are you sure that the initWithFrame constructor is being called and not some other one?

Comment: There is no constructor in objective-c.

Comment: @borrrden yes, I have tried setting breakpoint and it works.

Comment: @ViktorLexington Technically true but not a very "constructive" thing to say :p.  Initialization method then.

Comment: You shouldn't use a method name starting with "init" when it's not an initialiser.

Comment: @gnasher729 it's just a temporary method :)  I hope I won't have to keep it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the layer stuff is not yet initiated when your initWithFrame is called. This would lead to overwriting the layer information you set during initialization by iOS later on.

What I've used some time ago is an override of layoutSubViews. This would be something like the following in your case:

```
-(void)layoutSubViews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];  // Added due to remark below

    self.layer.mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
}
```

I hope this gives you an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, that's probably the root cause. For some reason assigning layer mask in `layoutSubviews` results in cell not being drawn at all, but that's probably another story.

Comment: oh, by the way, shouldn't we call `[super layoutSubViews]` here?

Comment: That wouldn't hurt. In my urge to give a didactical answer, I've skipped one statement to much ;-)

Comment: By the way, just now I realized that I tried setting breakpoint inside `initWithFrame` and printing `self.layer.mask` value with debugger, and it turns out that assignment is successful at this point, so after all this is not the cause.

Comment: Assignment is successful at this point, but afterward, iOS overwrites the assignment when initializing the layer data? When placing the statement in layoutSubview, iOS doesn't change the layer data anymore.

Comment: @PaintedBlack ok, I get it. But basically the same thing happens when I use ivar. Why ivar assigned in initializer loses its value?

Comment: @deville I think that your question is to general. There are a lot of possible reasons. Maybe you should create a new topic with an example of your code (where you lose the ivar initialization)?

Answer (score 2):

In the [Practical Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html) docu, Apple advices "*Don’t Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods...*", because the object being initialized might be in a half initialized state. The same is explained in [this blog](http://qualitycoding.org/objective-c-init/).
So I think you should not use the statement `self.layer.mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];` but access the `iVars` directly.

Comment: thanks for pointing out this pitfall, but thing is that problem remains even if I use ivar (take a look at my updated question).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of in `initWithFrame` do it in your `init` method

```
-(id)init
{
  if (self = [super init])
  {
    self.layer.mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thing is that my class is initialized using `dequeueReusableCell` method, and `init` is not called in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it in viewDidLoad.
In the init section you need to handle the parroters initialisation but the visual things in the view are being load only after.

or override
 -(void)layoutSubViews